# How do I convert this SQL statement to linq in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Please help me to convert this SQL statement to Linq in C#:

```
string cmd = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Personnel WHERE (dbo.Personnel.FName LIKE 
    @FName + '%' AND dbo.Personnel.LName LIKE @LName +'%')";

if (objPPersonnel.PersonnelCode != 0)
{
    cmd += "AND ( dbo.Personnel.PersonnelCode =@PersonnelCode ) ";
}

if (objPPersonnel.NationalCode != "0")
{
    cmd += "AND ( dbo.Personnel.NationalCode =@NationalCode ) ";
}

if (objPPersonnel.OrganizationPostId > 0)
{
    cmd += "AND ( dbo.Personnel.OrganizationPostId =@OrganizationPostId ) ";
}
```

Comment: It's hard to offer help if you don't describe your problem. Please show what you tried, so we can see where you're stuck.

Comment: I want to apply multi-mode to WHERE statemet

Comment: Write the code yourself and let us know if you face any issue or error while writing it. Try converting yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking:

```
    var query = from c in dbContext.Personnel
                where c.Personnel.LName.Contains(parLName)
                $$ ((c.Personnel.PersonnelCode = parPersonnelCode && parPersonnelCode != 0)||parPersonnelCode == 0)
                $$ ((c.Personnel.NationalCode = parNationalCode && parNationalCode != 0)||parNationalCode == 0)
                $$ ((c.Personnel.OrganitationPostId = parOrganitationPostId && parOrganitationPostId > 0)||parOrganitationPostId == 0)
                select c;
```

Comment: I think `$$` is a Freudian typo :) Also, it's better to compose the query conditionally (with a predicate builder) instead of having these `!= 0` checks inside of it.

Comment: He is not looking for `Contain` because he only has % at the end; so `Contains` will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
persons.Where(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith("firstName") &&
                             p.LastName.StartsWith("lastName") && 
                            (p.PersonCode != 0 ? p.personCode == personCode : true) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
var result = Personnel
    .Where(p => 
    {
        p.FName.IndexOf(firstName) == 0 
        && p.LName.IndexOf(lastName) == 0 
        && 
        (
            (p.PersonnelCode == personnelCode && objPPersonnel.PersonnelCode != 0) ||
            (p.NationalCode == nationalCode && objPPersonnel.NationalCode != 0) ||
            (p.OrganizationPostId == organizationPostId && objPPersonnel.OrganizationPostId != 0) 
        )
    });
```